# Static routes sync between windows servers

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, static-routes

Is there a way to run a "ROUTE ADD -P........" on a single Windows 2012 and higher servers, in a domain environment and have that route populate or sync with another server or servers in the same domain?

Kind of like a folder sync between servers, except in my case it's routing table.

Comment: You should be managing your routing at the correct place; in your routers and network. A “manual” route on a specific server is like an entry in a `etc/hosts` file, useful as an exception and manual override but not a generic solution.... If it is a setting relevant for all your servers , it should be set in the correct place

Comment: Thanks Bob. This is sort of a unique setup and only involves a few routes. Looks like it's a regedit placement. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Persisten